# What do you call a Markov kernel continuous w.r.t. the weak topology?

Tags: pr.probability, terminology, markov-chains

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Polish spaces and $K$ a Markov kernel from $X$ to $Y$. That is, $K$ is a mapping $X \times \mathcal{B}_Y \rightarrow [0,1]$ (where $\mathcal{B}_Y$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets on $Y$) s.t.

- For every $A \in \mathcal{B}_Y$, the mapping $K^A: X \rightarrow [0,1]$ defined by $K^A(x):=K(x,A)$ is Borel measurable.
- For every $x \in X$, the mapping $K_x: \mathcal{B}_Y \rightarrow [0,1]$ defined by $K_x(A):=K(x,A)$ is a probability measure on $Y$.

It seems natural to consider the additional condition on $K$ that $K_x$ depends continuously on $x$ in the sense of the given topology on $X$ and the *weak* topology on the space $\mathcal{P}(Y)$ of probability measures on $Y$. For example, if $K$ is deterministic (i.e. if for any $x \in X$, $K_x$ is a Dirac measure) this condition means that $K$ defines a continuous mapping from $X$ to $Y$.

> What is the standard name for this condition?

Comment: Some kind of [Feller continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feller-continuous_process)?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thank you! This looks right, some writers even use the name "Feller Markov kernel" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0086). Do you want to post this as an answer?

Comment: Is this motivated by the Robust filtering of Clarke in some way?  (Out of curiosity)

Comment: @AnnieTheKatsu Not really, it came up when I worked on this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.04630

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki While further exploring your question, I came across a [new related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467629/characterization-of-fellerian-kernels), which I've posted just now. I would greatly appreciate any insights you might be able to share. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment, this seems to be some kind of [Feller continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feller-continuous_process).

Having said that, I should emphasize that there is some confusion about the name "Feller" with regard to the properties of a Markov process, Markov transition function or a Markov kernel, and link to [Martin Hairer's comment about that](https://mathoverflow.net/a/280390/108637).